# How to call shortcode on button click

Tags: shortcode

i want to call a shortcode on button / link

```
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[wizard id=1]' ); ?>" class="btn" > CLICK TO OPEN SHORTCODE</a>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: [link]<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[wizard id=1]' ); ?>" > Whatever text for link</a>

Comment: What are you trying to do? are you referring to the WordPress editor,

Comment: downvoting, as without additional info the question is confusing server side and client side in a way that make it impossible to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a shortcode to PHP directly. However, each shortcode executes a function, so you can just add that function to your link code.

If your shortcode is something like this:

```
function my_custom_shortcode( $atts, $content= NULL) {
    shortcode function
}
add_shortcode ( 'my_custom_shortcode' , 'my_custom_shortcode' );
```

use this in your link:

```
<a href="<?php my_custom_shortcode(); ?>" class="btn" > CLICK TO OPEN SHORTCODE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a shortcode on button click, you can not directly use PHP within HTML attributes like href. Instead, you need to use JS to achieve this functionality.

```
<!-- HTML code for the button -->
<a href="#" id="shortcodeButton" class="btn">CLICK TO OPEN SHORTCODE</a>

<!-- JavaScript code -->
<script>
    // Add an event listener to the button
    document.getElementById('shortcodeButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // Prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Call the shortcode using JavaScript
        var shortcodeResult = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[wizard id=1]"); ?>';
        
        // Redirect or do something with the result
        // For example, you can redirect to the result URL
        window.location.href = shortcodeResult;
    });
</script>
```

your shortcode function [wizard id=1] is correctly defined and will return the desired output